# I have urine incontinence, can I do tayammum?

Tags: practical-islam, tayammum, incontinence

I have urine incontinence and it makes salat and wudu very difficult to do. Sometimes I even do wudu 3 times just to pray 1 salat.

Can I do tayammum because doing wudu and repeating salat everytime I drop a drop of urine is very hard and exhausting? Isn't Islam "dinu yusr" so it makes practicing it easy for the muslims in condition?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1):

You can't do tayammum if the conditions allowing it are not fulfilled. And those are either the absence of water or the use of water being harmful (causing harm for example death risk).

If you have urine incontinence you must perform one wudu' for every prayer right before you want to pray and don't care about any drops that come after you've done it right, as long as you pray once having finished your wudu'.
I'm pretty confident that you may find an answer with more details and evidences for this part of the question on the site.

Else you should rather ask a scholar and physician and clarify whether or not your case is a case of inconvenience.